# What is the best browser to tackle the memory issues I am having?

Tags: memory, browser

So I am botting a flash game on 3 PC, but I am running out of memory. Of course this will happen eventually, but what are some browsers that use a minimum of memory? I could increase the paging file maybe if there is no maximum memory limit, it doesn't need to run very fast, I am hoping for 1 frame every 5 seconds at least.

Comment: If you are running out of memory then you have a memory leak in your botting program.  You should be able to run a system, running the same program, for an infinite amount of time without running out of memory.  I you cannot do that then you have a memory leak

Comment: I am not running the bot yet, I am still writing the script. However, chromes physical memory was over a gig.

Comment: It just keeps increasing.

Comment: I know chrome has memory leaks, is there a browser that doesn't have this issue?

Comment: I should mention, it's a Facebook game, and Facebook is the one using all my memory, not the flash game itself.

Comment: There are a dozenf browsers available in [Portable Apps](https://portableapps.com/apps/internet). You can try any or all of these without installing. The PA team are pretty good at keeping their apps up to date with the latest released versions.

Comment: Good idea, I am already using a portable chrome so I can use multiple accounts. Also, I will try using Facebook gameroom instead, maybe that will cut Facebook out  of the equation, since the game itself seems to use a tenth as much memory as the page itself over time.

Comment: Do you actually run out of virtual memory or i something you only believe will happen.  I have no problem having Facebook just sitting in a tab in Chrome/Firefox/IE11/Edge by themselves without an add-on these browsers should not leak memory.

Comment: I don't just mean Facebook, I mean Facebook on a game tab, a game designed to keep running a JS file constantly. The JS file makes sure you are not AFK or haven't left the page. Chrome was using 1.1 gigs of memory with only 24 hours of use. I can raise the amount of memory it will use, but at this rate, I will have to keep starting the whole thing over and over every few days. Chrome just crashed a few hours ago, couldn't handle the lack of ram access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that...

- IE/Firefox Flash plugins are (in my experience) rather unstable or they have their own memory leaks
- Firefox is going to be dropping support for NPAPI plugins pretty soon
- Google Chrome still maintains PepperFlash and it runs natively inside Chrome

...you're probably best-off using Chrome in the long run. However, there's no harm in doing an experiment with an instance on each PC and recording some proper statistics.

Chrome has its own special task manager for keeping track of CPU and memory usage, which is pretty neat.

[image: Chrome Task Manager]

For Firefox and probably other browsers not based on Chromium, you'll have to rely on Windows Task Manager to find out what the plugin is up to.

[image: Windows Task Manager]

In these examples, you can see they're roughly the same, for they have both just loaded the same Flash applet. If the game or Flash itself has a memory leak, you'll be able to track it here.

Comment: I get a little more indepth information than task manager actually, I use Process Explorer by sysinternals. It's a great program. As for trying chrome, that is the browser I am currently having issues with. Perhaps if killing the tab, (which is eating all my memory) didn't also close pepper, it would work, but pepper relies on the tab, and suspending the tab freezes pepper :(

Comment: What issue are you having with PepperFlash? And can the Flash applet be run independently of a browser, or is it a browser-based game?

Comment: The latter comment seems to ring true, I thought it was pepper being reliant on the browser, but yeah it's probably dependent on keeping my Facebook tab open and running. My problem with Pepper is simple, if I am reliant on the tab I opened pepper in, than I have to keep that process open. If I have to keep that process open, then the memory leaks will build up until the tab crashes, like what just happened an hour ago.

Comment: OK so you believe (or have stats to show) the memory leaks are in the webpage itself, not the Flash applet. that's a little trickier. Chrome and Firefox do have performance-monitoring devtools to help track those down.

Comment: Yes I am sure, I checked the memory tab in chrome, and I checked both private bytes and working set in Process Explorer. private bytes were at about 1.1 gig during the crash, while working set was about 950mb. I checked the PID in the chrome memory-internals tab, matched it with the tab title or flash applet, and experimented. Even when inside fullscreen flash will freeze whenever I freeze the tab, and crash whenever I kill the tab. The flash applet itself was only using about 120mb virtual memory after running a full day.

Comment: You'd have to take some snapshots with the JS profiler to see what things look like after a few minutes, versus when it's close to crashing. Then you can perhaps hack the webpage code to prune it, or disable a feature. Not sure if you could disable JS entirely while continuing to use Flash, though.

Comment: That's a neat idea, but it's I have messed with NoScript before, so I know for a fact it's the official Facebook JS file I would have to mess with, and I would have to do it every time they update too. Is there a way to take a snapshot of the program, erase the contents of a matching program, and restore the state, like save states in an emulator perhaps?

Comment: Not that I know of! You could try doing fancy stuff in VMs (and therefore have several games running on each PC). VMs can save and restore their state, but it takes some time.
Regarding JS, you could try disabling JS entirely from Devtools, or using Adblock/uBlock to block individual scripts until you have as little as possible that still works.

Comment: Restoring a VM! Brilliant! I will try that :D. I guess I can try the JS thing too, but I am not looking forward to updating the JS file every time the game updates. A VM would be a million times better though! I could shut it down, restore the state, over and over and over. And I would only need to activate the little known bug I am botting once! It's kind of hard to do lol, your player must time out first. It may or may not work though, I am pretty sure the online bidding room I am connected to closes when the final player leaves, and I would be the final player.

Comment: Glad to help! Hope it's worth an upvote at least. :)

Comment: Sure thing :) thanks for the help, I have a lot of stuff to try now, at least 3 different plans. One is bound to work, and then my item harvest bot will be complete :)

Comment: I clicked upvote, but I am new to this site, so it doesn't show sorry :( thats a dumb setting. I guess its so that people cant make accounts and upvote themselves.

Comment: Oh, yeah. Crikey... It's been so long, I forgot, you need 15 rep to upvote things! Well, I guess you could just accept the answer, so it gets marked as closed. Up to you!